# Rails/Devise and "Completed 401 Unauthorized" after being redirected to app from setting up Stripe account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments

My users are directed to Stripe Connect as part of the onboarding process for my app. When they finish, Stripe sends them back to my site with two params in the url: `code` and an encoded `state`. In this case, the latter param was previously saved to the db in decoded form, then encoded and passed to Stripe to prevent CSRF forgery.

The problem is that users are signed out when redirected back to my app upon the first pass through onboarding, whereas the second pass goes through just fine. `Completed 401 Unauthorized` in the console is all I have to go off of.

```
2020-07-06T00:29:24.121304+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/onboard/id_verification?code=ac_Tau1R4hyn47LGrwiisUpFDEEMmpWVBrw&state=YTVmNGZmOTUtMjc3ZC00YjIyLThjZDctNTliODBlMzY1OThk" for ###.##.##.## at 2020-07-06 00:29:24 +0000
2020-07-06T00:29:24.123838+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Users::OnboardsController#id_verification as HTML
2020-07-06T00:29:24.123891+00:00 app[web.1]: Parameters: {"code"=>"ac_Tau1R4hyn47LGrwiisUpFDEEMmpWVBrw", "state"=>"YTVmNGZmOTUtMjc3ZC00YjIyLThjZDctNTliODBlMzY1OThk"}
2020-07-06T00:29:24.127212+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2020-07-06T00:29:24.261889+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ###.##.##.## at 2020-07-06 00:29:24 +0000
2020-07-06T00:29:24.265479+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
```

Assuming a happy path (decoded `state` param equals what is saved to the db, `code` is `present?`, and `stripe_user_id` is either `present?` or `nil`) the user is taken to a form for uploading some documentation.

This is the relevant controller action:

```
class Users::OnboardsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :prevent_return_to_onboarding, only: [:username, :stripe, :id_verification, :queued]

 def id_verification
  if params[:state].blank? || params[:code].blank?
   redirect_to onboard_stripe_path
  elsif Base64.decode64(params[:state]) != current_user.stripe_state_token
   flash[:error] = "CSRF forgery detected"
   redirect_to onboard_stripe_path
  elsif Base64.decode64(params[:state]) == current_user.stripe_state_token && params[:code].present? && current_user.stripe_user_id.present?
   @user = current_user
   respond_to do |format| 
    format.html { render '/users/onboard/id_verification.html.erb' } 
   end
  elsif Base64.decode64(params[:state]) == current_user.stripe_state_token && params[:code].present? && current_user.stripe_user_id == nil
   get_stripe_id = StripeUser.connect(params[:code])
   current_user.stripe_user_id = get_stripe_id.stripe_user_id
   current_user.save
   @user = current_user

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render '/users/onboard/id_verification.html.erb' } 
   end
  end
 end

 def prevent_return_to_onboarding
  if current_user.stripe_user_id.present? && current_user.identity_doc.present? && current_user.approved == true
   redirect_to root_path
  end
 end
end
```

Does anyone have any insight as to the source of that `Completed 401 Unauthorized` error? Thank you!

Comment: Could it be that the URL is not the same? Such as the user is signed in to [https://www.example.com](https://www.example.com) and the redirect ur is set to [https://example.com](https://example.com)?

Comment: I think this may be the issue! How can I make the session for those two addresses shared? If I go to twitter.com and www.twitter.com, the session is the same.